# String to javascript in Firefox extension (without eval(), setTimeout or new Function)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm passing strings such as `"getElementById('div1')"` or `"getElementsByName('div2')"` from a remote server depending on the page the user opens. How can I run these as javascript in the page without using any of the above mentioned functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = 'alert("hello");';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: This is awesome! Do you also know if it's allowed by Firefox?

Comment: Not sure if there are security policies in place that will prevent an add-on from doing this, but it's worth a shot. If it doesn't work, let me know. I'll update my answer so at least anyone else who stumbles upon this page will know.

Comment: I tried to submit a new version, the auto validation returned this line as deprecated `window.content.document.createElement('script');` and doesn't work without the `window.content`. Any other possible suggestions?

Comment: Regarding Firefox, this is allowed... If you want, you can even add an 'src' to the script instead of the innerHTML (both works!) Regarding the validation, I think browser.contentDocument is preferred (though I have no proof to back it up)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use document.write. I don't know if you can use that for javascript, but I recommend that the server should pass codes plus an element name to the client, and then execute a certain method based off of that.